# How to increase max_locks_per_transaction

Tags: macos, postgresql, sequelize.js

I've been performing kind of intensive schema dropping and creating over a PostgreSQL server,

> ERROR:  out of shared memory
>
> HINT:  You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction.

I need to increase max_locks_per_transaction but how can i increase it in **MAC OSX**

Answer (score 51, accepted):

you might find ../data/postgresql.conf file, then edit with notepad, set max_locks_per_transaction = 1024
if it looks like # max_locks_per_transaction... you must remove #.

it must look like that:
max_locks_per_transaction = 1024        # min 10

than save it and restart postgresql

Comment: Location of this file in Mac (Postgres was installed using Homebrew) is `/usr/local/var/postgres/`

Comment: Can we set max_locks_per_transaction using query ?

Comment: Yes, the query is `ALTER SYSTEM set max_locks_per_transaction = 1024`

Answer (score 22):

It is a setting in your postgresql.conf if you do not know where that file is run `SHOW config_file;` on an sql prompt/window.

Then when you have modified that file restart postgresql, I don't know how you do that on MacOS a reboot will work of course.

Comment: If you installed Postgres using Brew, you can `brew services restart postgresql`

Comment: And if you use the app, you can click on the systray icon. In that menu, you first "stop", then "start".

Answer (score 2):

For **postgress docker** container ,enter the following commands:

```
  docker exec -it <container_id_or_name> sh
```

Replace **container_id_or_name** with the container id or name

```
cd /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Use **sed** to edit the "postgresql.conf" file and update the "max_locks_per_transaction" parameter:

```
sed -i 's/^max_locks_per_transaction = .*/max_locks_per_transaction = new_value/' postgresql.conf
```

Replace **new_value** with the desired new value for the "max_locks_per_transaction" parameter.