# Spring Batch Processing - Postgresql Out of shared memory

Tags: postgresql, out-of-memory, spring-batch

We are using spring batch processing to process a file which have 10,000 records and our database is postgresql. In our process we are reading the file using flat file item reader and we are processing each record as follows:

```
Loop Record

    Insert Table 1;

    Insert Table 2;

    Insert Table 3, 4, 5;

End Loop
```

At the end of the process we are getting PSQL Exception which says:

> Out of shared memory exception. Hint : Increase max locks per transaction.

Is there a way to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

As already stated by the error message, you need to increase the `max_locks_per_transaction` within the `postgresql.conf` as documented in the 
[postgres documentation: 18.12. Lock Management](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-locks.html) or in this stack overflow article: [How to increase max_locks_per_transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654766/how-to-increase-max-locks-per-transaction)

Comment: I second this answer.