# Why is my Django database flush command not working?

Tags: django, postgresql

I've been chasing an error message regarding the python manage.py flush command for several weeks.  When I issue the command and confirm the flush....I get...

CommandError: Database my_app_db couldn't be flushed. Possible
reasons:

- The database isn't running or isn't configured correctly.
- At least one of the expected database tables doesn't exist.
- The SQL was invalid.
  Hint: Look at the output of 'django-admin sqlflush'. That's the SQL this command wasn't able to run.

After chasing...upgrading various components...trying several different avenues....I still can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally figure this out after grasping for straws and looking through database logs.  In the database logs in my POSTGRESQL directory...( I'm running my development environment on Windows10 )....I found the following error message...

023-04-11 15:53:57.386 CDT [20072] ERROR:  out of shared memory
2023-04-11 15:53:57.386 CDT [20072] HINT:  You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction.

I did find this answer after a bit of googling and another article directed me to this reference...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654766/how-to-increase-max-locks-per-transaction

In the Postgresql directory....Under data....the file in question was just a file call postgresql.  It is a CONF File Type.

Go into this file with notepad...and all the way towards the bottom in the LOCK MANAGEMENT section....

You will see....

#max_locks_per_transaction = 10

You need to uncomment this line and update the 10 to 1024 so that it looks like...

max_locks_per_transaction = 1024

Now save the file and from what I've read you can just opt to start and stop the Postgresql service, I chose to reboot.  After I rebooted my system, the error message went away and I was able to successfully flush the database.  Hopefully this saves someone else weeks worth of banging their head against the wall.